# GCM Dry run gives canonical as invalid registration tokens

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I have written a java program to test the list of regtoken in our database is invalid or canonical.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < registration_ids.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(new Gson().toJson(results.get(i), LinkedHashMap.class))
            .getAsJsonObject();
    String key = "";
    if (jsonObject.keySet().size() == 2) {
        key = "Canonical";
    } else if (jsonObject.has("message_id")) {
    } else if (jsonObject.get("error").getAsString().equalsIgnoreCase("InvalidRegistration")) {
        key = "Invalid";
    } else if (jsonObject.get("error").getAsString().equalsIgnoreCase("NotRegistered")) {
        key = "Invalid";
    }
    if (key.equals("Canonical")) {
        createFile(registration_ids.get(i) + ","
                + jsonObject.get("registration_id").getAsString().concat(System.lineSeparator()), key);
    } else if (key.equals("Invalid"))
        createFile(registration_ids.get(i).concat(System.lineSeparator()), key);
}
```

But after validating some hundred thousand reg tokens, gcm print some reg id's as invalid and later returns the same reg token validation result as canonical.
Why this behaviour?

Comment: Hi masSdev. Just wanted to verify, are you using GCM or FCM? If it is GCM, are the tokens from the GCM inplementationas well? Would you be able to test the same for an FCM scenario?

Comment: i am using gcm , i am doing a http post call to [https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send] with body as `{
  "collapse_key": "demo",
  "dryRun":true,
  "time_to_live": 0,
  "delay_while_idle": false,
  "data": {
   "openapp":"false","psinterval":0,"rurl":"http://www.yahoo.com","nicon":"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/qa-mmxpushnotificationimg/55560/icon.gif","title":"Type 2 New","message":"Hello MMX","ntype":"2","cid":"55560"
  },
  "registration_ids":["APA91bFMTaIi93TgID2hoT8MAhxmhq_bZDN3R9tX...."]
}`

Comment: i can test same with fcm too

Comment: if there any issue if we try with simple spring rest template??

Comment: Hi masSdev. Sorry it's been a while. I wasn't able to understand, were you able to test it with FCM? Was it the same behavior? I don't see any issue if you test it with template. So long as the request sent and the response is received properly, it should be fine.

Comment: Also, `delay_while_idle` is already deprecated, so you should might as well remove it from your payload.